# Python Error: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, arrays, syntax-error

```py
def openMap(uArr, oArr, i):
    y = int(input("Row Number"))
    x = int(input("Column Number"))
    uArr[y,x] = oArr[y,x]
    printMap(uArr)
    if oArr[y,x] == "X":
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

`uArr` refers to the *user* array and `oArr` to the *original* array.

I get this error:

> list indices must be integers or slices, not a tuple

Can someone help to debug this?

Comment: Perhaps you mean```if oArr[y][x] == "X":``` You cannot pass 2 numbers for indexing a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a normal Python multidimensional list, you can't access elements as `uArr[y, x]`. Instead use `uArr[y][x]`.

Comment: Yes, realized that just after posting this, but that still shows this error

Comment: Please edit your question with your updated code. Have you replaced all the occurences?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean `if oArr[y][x] == "X":`? You cannot pass 2 numbers for indexing a list.

By passing `[y,x]` it means `oArr[(y,x)]` And list indexing needs an integer.
You should do:

```
if oArr[y][x] == "X":
```

Answer (score 0):

The error-message indicates a common syntax error in Python.

#### Syntax-error when indexing

> list indices must be integers or slices, not a tuple

It is caused by using the wrong syntax when indexing a list (or array). What your code used as index was `x,y` was interpreted as tuple like `(x,y)`.

Correct would be either a **single** integer, like `array[1]` or `array[x]` or a slice like `array[1:2]` to get second to third element.

See explained in article [TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str](https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str/).

The indexes in any multi-dimensional array or list must be added in separate brackets. So `[x][y][z]` indexes a single element in a cube or 3D-array, whereas your 2-dimensional array will just use something like `[x][y]`.

#### Hot to fix

To fix it, simply replace all `[y,x]` by `[y][x]`.

```py
def openMap(uArr, oArr, i):
    y = int(input("Row Number"))
    x = int(input("Column Number"))  # fixed a typo

    uArr[y][x] = oArr[y][x]
    printMap(uArr)
    
    if oArr[y][x] == "X":
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

#### Bonus-Tip: Validate user-input to avoid out-of-bounds errors

What happens if the user enters `-1` or `999999999999`? Does your array or list allow negative indices or have a size that large?

You should check before and ask for a correct input then.

```
    last_row = len(oArr)-1  # last index because zero-based
    y = last_row + 1  # initially out-of-bounds to enter the loop
    while not 0 <= y <= last_row:
        y = int(input("Row Number ({}..{}): ".format(0, last_row)))
    
    last_col = len(oArr[0])-1  # suppose it's quadratic = all rows have same length
    x = last_col + 1  # initially out-of-bounds to enter the loop
    while not 0 <= x <= last_col:
        x = int(input("Column Number ({}..{}):".format(0, last_col)))
```

Note: Technically a negative index like `-1` will point to the last element, `-2` to the element before last, and so on.

See also related questions:

- [Determine Whether Integer Is Between Two Other Integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628791/determine-whether-integer-is-between-two-other-integers#13628825)
- [How to index a list based on user input, and print the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568565/how-to-index-a-list-based-on-user-input-and-print-the-result#42568806)
- [IndexError: list index out of range : when a element is poped out of array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66118483/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-when-a-element-is-poped-out-of-array-in-py)
- [Python - Input Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157374/python-input-validation#19157818)